# Toggle "enter on submit"

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an input field that is validated against a database through AJAX on keyUp().

If the entered text is satisfactory a  is enabled.

I want to also toggle the enter on submit for the text input field.

```
<div id="faq_dupe" class="center-modal">
    <form id="faq_form" onsubmit="AJAXsendData(); hideModal('faq_dupe'); return false;">
        <input id="faq_dupe_search" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 00AA1" class="noEnterSubmit"/>
        <button id="faq_dupe_img" type="submit" disabled>
            <img src="/img/val-no.png"/>
            <div>Submit</div>
        </button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.noEnterSubmit').keypress(function(e){
            if ( e.which == 13 ) return false;
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#faq_dupe_search').keydown(function() {
            var faqimg = '<img src="/img/load-a-40px.gif"/><div>Submit</div>';
            document.getElementById('faq_dupe_img').innerHTML = faqimg;
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#faq_dupe_search').keyup(function() {
            AJAXvalFAQid($('#faq_dupe_search').val());
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

I have AJAXvalFAQid() adding and removing the .noEnterSubmit class.

As of right now hitting enter will not execute the scripts in onsubmit="" whether the .noEnterSubmit class is applied or not.

Here is what I ened up using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onsubmit(event) {
        if(noEnterSubmit === true){
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
            sendData();
            hideModal('faq_dupe');
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Changed behavior in `AJAXvalFAQid()` to take Frits van Campen's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to just have one submit function. It could look like this:

```
function onsubmit(event) {
    if (input_is_valid()) {
        // all is well, let the event continue
    } else {
        event.preventDefault(); // block the submit
        show_errors();
    }
}
```

with

```
<form id="faq_form">..</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#faq_form").submit(onsubmit);
</script>
```

Comment: A combination of this and @idrumgood answer is just what I needed.

Comment: See above for what I end up doing.

Comment: I am a strong opponent of using `hasClass` in logic (or `hasClass` in general, it's a _codesmell_). If you're doing an `addClass` somewhere why not keep a boolean flag to indicate the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

If `.noEnterSubmit` is present on the input when you do your initial binding, it will always be bound to that input, whether or not the class is present. You need to check for the class after the keyup happens like so:

```
$('#faq_dup_search').keypress(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('noEnterSubmit') && e.which == 13){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thinking about it being permanently bound. The scripts in `onclick=""` were will being called though.